# Extract word by Regex postgreSQL

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

a colums include code like 'a357' , 'b123' with many word and i want to extract them
it work with

```
select *, regexp_matches(col1,'a\d{3}') from table
```

but i also want the 'b123' code then i write this code not work:

```
select *, regexp_matches(col1,'(a|b)\d{3}') from table
```

where as (a|b) is regex. Please show me solution or any other way not regexp_matches because i need to trim '{}' sign after that.

Comment: You need `'[ab]\d{3}'` or `'(?:a|b)\d{3}'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank a lot, my problem solved, but it closed too soon, select *, substring(campaign_name from '(?:a|b|B|A)\d{2,3}'
--'[abAB]\d{2,3}'
)
from table

Answer (score -1):

The issue is the subexpression in parentheses.  As the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) explains:

> If a match is found, and the pattern contains parenthesized
> subexpressions, then the result is a text array whose n'th element is
> the substring matching the n'th parenthesized subexpression of the
> pattern.

In your case, this is easily fixed by using a character class:

```
regexp_matches(col1, '[ab]\d{3}')
```

Comment: thank a lot, my problem solved, but it closed too soon, select *, substring(campaign_name from '(?:a|b|B|A)\d{2,3}'
--'[abAB]\d{2,3}'
)
from table